# Matching multidimensional array value with two values from other array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array name `$main_array`

```
         $main_array = [
            [
                'product_id' => '1',
                'values' => '1"'
            ],
            [
                'product_id' => '4',
                'values' => '1"'
            ],
            [
                'product_id' => '4',
                'values' => 'blue'
            ],
            [
                'product_id' => '5',
                'values' => 'blue'
            ]
        ];
```

I want to check values from other array

```
$check_array = [
        '1"','blue'
    ];
```

Find product_id where `1"` && `blue` both matching

Expected output ::

```
$output = [

    [
        'product_id' => '4',
        'values' => '1"'
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => '4',
        'values' => 'blue'
    ]

];
```

Comment: your output contradicts with your condition

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to store matching elements using the product id as key.

```
$include = [] ;
foreach ($main_array as $key => $item) {
    // if values match to $check_array
    if (in_array($item['values'], $check_array)) {
        // store using product id as key
        $pid = $item['product_id'] ;
        $include[$pid][] = $key;
    }
}

// Filter to keep only items that match with all conditions
$include = array_filter($include, function($a) use ($check_array) { 
    return count($a) == count($check_array) ; 
}) ;
$include = reset($include) ; // Get the first

// Recreate final array :
$out = [] ;
foreach ($include as $elem) {
    $out[] = $main_array[$elem] ;
}
print_r($out);
```

Will outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 4
            [values] => 1"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 4
            [values] => blue
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use nested foreach cycles. Supposed that $check_array containes two fields, you can write a code like this:

```
$output = array();
$match_array = array();
//check the first field correspondence
foreach ($main_array as $key1=>$sub_main) {
  foreach ($sub_main as $key2=>$item) {
    if ($check_array[0] == $item['values']) {
      $match_array[] = $item['product_id'];
    }
  }
}
//try to match the second field
foreach ($main_array as $key1=>$sub_main) {
  foreach ($sub_main as $key2=>$item) {
    if ($check_array[1] == $item['values']) {
      if (in_array($item['product_id'], $match_array) {
        $output[] = array($item['product_id'], $check_array[1]);
        $output[] = array($item['product_id'], $check_array[2]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```